# How I can make Sliding layout from bottom like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-sliding

I want to make sliding layout from bottom to the center, like this:

[image]

[image]

I saw Umano SlidingLayout but it slides to the top.

How I can make something like this?

Comment: Add the layout normally, but set the margin to -100dp (or similar, you'll have to tweak until you get the right negative margin), then, on click, get the layout params and change the margin back to 0. You can even add animations. If you need me to i can write some code to get you going, but it isnt that hard at all.

Comment: Cool idea, I can add animation on button click, but how I can make real drag from bottom to the center?

Comment: For real drag you'd need to set up a touch event listener and get the X and Y of the touch event and update the layout params every time the user drags it.

Comment: Post some code as answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Alright, can you post your current xml? with the bottom layout in the middle of the activity.